# How can I do a Django query where I can filter on a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I am trying to do a query using Django but I got a problem, here is my query :

```
A = User.objects.filter(country['Europe']['South']='Italy')
```

But it does not work ...

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: What do you actually want as output?

Comment: What is `country` here?

Answer (score 0):

Django ORM's general syntax for the thing you are trying is as follow:

`Model.objects.filter(<field_defined_in_model>=<valid value>)`

Now, `User` model is pre_defined and can't decode the dictionary value as a column. The field choices for the column to be filtered can be referred here:[Django User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
A = User.objects.filter(country__Europe__South='Italy')
```